# Is it possible to make all values in scala object lazy with a single keyword

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Or are `val`s in scala objects lazy by default?

Anyway, if it's necessary to declare a `val` in an object lazy by using `lazy`, is it possible to do something like

```
lazy object SomeObject
```

or (like you do in c++)

```
object A {
lazy:
    val a
    val b
    ...
}
```

Because I would like to be lazy and not have to relabel all my `val`s `lazy val`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your first question ("are `val`s in scala objects lazy by default?"): No, not exactly, but the objects themselves are *kind of* lazy, which may be lazy enough. From 5.4 ("Object Definitions") of [the Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> Note that the value defined by an object definition is instantiated
>   lazily. The `new m$cls` constructor is evaluated not at the point of
>   the object definition, but is instead evaluated the first time `m` is
>   dereferenced during execution of the program (which might be never at
>   all).

So, for example, if we have these three objects:

```
object X {
  val answer = { println("Here's X's answer!"); 42 }
}

object Y {
  lazy val answer = { println("Here's Y's answer!"); 1 }
}

object Z extends App {
  println("Here we go.")
  println(X)
  println(Y)
  println(X.answer)
  println(Y.answer)
}
```

Then when we run `Z`, we see the following:

```
Here we go.
Here's X's answer!
X$@38d24866
Y$@f1aa6ce
42
Here's Y's answer!
1
```

So the `val` in `X` isn't lazy, but it's also not evaluated until the first time we use `X`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: no, it is **not** possible (unless you're not doing some insane crunching with macros).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, objects are initialized lazily already:

```
object Y {
  println("aqui")
  val a = 0
}

Y.a  // runs body of Y
```

Second, if you are happy with the multiple `val`s being lazily initialized *at once*, you can use pattern extraction from a tuple:

```
object X {
  val a = 0
  lazy val (b, c) = {
    println("aqui")
    (1, "hallo")
  }
}

X.a  // runs body of X, initialises strict vals
X.b  // initialises both b and c
X.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of insanity (@om-nom-nom), it might be possible to adapt the [Autoproxy plugin](https://github.com/kevinwright/Autoproxy-Lite) such that it creates lazy wrappers. That would be ... interesting. \

In general, a Scala compiler plugin would allow you to do this. You could tag lazy objects via a marker trait or an annotation and then let the compiler plugin do the rewriting. Writing compiler plugins is not the easiest thing to do, but it can be fun nevertheless.

Comment: I suppose adding the lazy flag right after parser phase to be near trivial... i am only supposing thought.

Comment: @pedrofurla In my experience, the learning curve for writing your first compiler plugin is pretty steep. The actual task, however, should indeed be fairly easy.